# Is it safe o update row from translation table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, localisation, inline-translations

To update inline translation value without enabling inline translation because its prod environment so Is it safe to update row from "translation" table using update query

### |key_id | string      | store_id | translate      | locale | crc_string |

### |  14 | Item in Cart |      1 | Produkt i jjsanhj | nb_NO  | 2629046627 |

So i am planing to update the above record using "update translation set translate='abc' where key_id=14";

Kindly advise
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine. The only relation to consider on the `translate` table is its foreign key relation to `store.store_id`, but this isn't relevant to what you're doing. You may need to flush cache after making your change, but it shouldn't hurt anything.